# Perform $lookup to array of object id's in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have got the two collection named 
**BlogCategory** and 
**SubBlogCategory** .The document of the BlogCategory consists the array of objectId's of subcategory id.

The category document is as follows

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5af2c6e8bfab7269e9a42ded"), 
    "title" : "Javascript", 
    "subcategory" : [
        ObjectId("5af29fcc9a52623b7088ef4e"), 
        ObjectId("5aebf78681273424e5f55ecc")
     ]
}
```

The subcategory document is as follows

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5af29fcc9a52623b7088ef4e"), 
    "title" : "Reactjs"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aebf78681273424e5f55ecc"), 
    "title" : "Vuejs", 
}
```

How can I populate the subcategory documents on the category documents while getting all the documents of the collection category?

I have used the following query but its only populating the single id of the array

```
db.BlogCategory.aggregate([
   {
     $unwind: "$subcategory"
   },
   {
      $lookup:
      {
          from: "SubBlogCategory",
          localField: "subcategory",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "sub_doc"
     }
   }
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to `$unwind` here... $unwind duplicates each document in the pipeline, once per array element.

```
db.BlogCategory.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup:
      {
          from: *Collection_Name*,
          localField: "subcategory",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "sub_doc"
     }
   }
])
```

if you are using mongodb version 3.6 then you can use pipeline

```
db.BlogCategory.aggregate([
              { "$lookup": {
                "from": *Collection_Name*,
                "let": { "subcategory": "$subcategory" },
                "pipeline": [
                   { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$subcategory" ] } } }
                 ],
                 "as": "sub_doc"
              }}
            ])
```

Comment: I am using core more mongodb. populate function doesnot work

Comment: its not populating anything.

Comment: I think your collection name would not be correct.. try to use correct one

Comment: I am using the correct Collection name. The value for the key sub_doc is empty

Comment: I have used it in my collection works perfect... what name you are using??? and also which mongodb version you are using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170800/discussion-between-chyangba-and-ashish-choudhary).

Comment: The second query gives me this error
Unable to execute the selected commands

Mongo Server error (MongoCommandException): Command failed with error 40081: '$in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing' on server localhost:27017. 

The full response is:
{ 
    "ok" : 0.0, 
    "errmsg" : "$in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing", 
    "code" : NumberInt(40081), 
    "codeName" : "Location40081"
}

Comment: use `$eq` for single id

Comment: when I run the query db.BlogCategory.findOne({_id:ObjectId("5af2c6e8bfab7269e9a42ded")})

I am getting 

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5af2c6e8bfab7269e9a42ded"), 
    "title" : "Javascript", 
    "subcategory" : [
        ObjectId("5af29fcc9a52623b7088ef4e"), 
        ObjectId("5aebf78681273424e5f55ecc")
     ]
}


How can I populate the ids for the single document???